# Should the thinking tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should the [thinking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thinking) tag be removed?

It seems vague, is used in only 13 question, and has only 1 follower. I'm thinking it should be pruned.

Comment: FYI - when a tag has no questions using it (and probably some other requirements too like no tag wiki), it is automatically removed up as part of the nightly cleanup script. If we *really* want to get rid of it (like 'homework' tag) so it can't be used again, it gets burninated. Yes, thats apparently a technical term